# Getting an error while converting angular 10 to angular 11

Tags: angular11

installed node verion 16.13     previously it was node v 14.18.1

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> Blockquote

npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: RestaurantIntranet.WebUI@1.0.0

npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1001.7

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1101.2" from the root project

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1101.2" from the root project
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.1.2

npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli

npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1101.2

npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1101.2" from the root project

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Comment: dont know why its coming

Comment: What was the last command you used to get this error?

Comment: @Ambujsahu  manually changed package.json

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this was old and new package.json

Comment: but its not worked

Comment: you should not do this manually , refer official docs for step on how to upgrade to angular 11. Try using this command it might help `ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force`

Comment: Let me try this again @Ambujsahu

Answer (score 0):

Got an Ans  we have to run this command **force** as if we use normal *ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11*  it won`t work so used

> ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force